# Why dosent this custom library draw shapes? Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So I wrote this small utility, which I will be expanding, just to save some time, but it dosent seem to draw the shape, even though there are no compiler issues?

Custom class:

```
package ezd.easydraw
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class EasyDraw extends MovieClip
    {
        public var _root:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        public function DrawCircle(xpos:Number=200.0, ypos:Number=200.0, r:int=50, color:uint=0x00FF00, alph:Number=1.0) 
        {
            _root = MovieClip(_root);
            var circle:Shape = new Shape;
            circle.graphics.beginFill(color, alph);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(xpos, ypos, r);
            circle.graphics.endFill();
            _root.addChild(circle);
        }
        public function DrawRect(xpos:Number=200.0, ypos:Number=200.0, w:int=50, h:int=50, color:uint=0x00FF00, alph:Number=1.0)
        {
            _root = MovieClip(_root);
            var rect:Shape = new Shape;
            rect.graphics.beginFill(color, alph);
            rect.graphics.drawRect(xpos, ypos, w, h);
            rect.graphics.endFill();
            _root.addChild(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

And the "main" window to draw the shapes:

```
import ezd.easydraw.EasyDraw;
stop();
var ezd:EasyDraw = new EasyDraw();
stage.focus = ezd._root;
ezd.DrawCircle(300, 300, 500);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

1. `_root`
2. the use of the display list and how it works
3. the design in general

---

**That `_root` variable is totally useless.** You probably copied that from some online tutorial. It's a bad practice and leads to worse practices. It recreates functionality that's already there. Do not use it.

Next up, `EasyDraw` class itself. That class is basically an empty container with methods to add shapes to it. Given the general structure of the display list of adding `DisplayObject`s to `DisplayObjectContainer`s, this seems to be unnecessarily coupled. Why would the container bring the methods to *create* the children? Instead create separate classes for circles and rectangles in an object oriented manner. Then just add them to a `Sprite` object if you need a container. There's no need for `EasyDraw`.

The outlined concept could lead to two classes like those below. They are based on your code. Pretty naive object oriented thinking here: You want a circle? Create a class for that! You want a rectangle? Create a class for that! But it gets the job done.

```
package ezd.easydraw
{
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class CircleShape extends Shape
    {
        public function DrawCircle(r:Number=50, color:uint = 0) 
        {
            graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, r);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package ezd.easydraw
{
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class RectangleShape extends Shape
    {
        public function RectangleShape(w:Number = 50, h:Number = 50, color:uint = 0)
        {
            graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
            graphics.drawRect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

I made some adjustments which are mostly personal preference, feel free to do this your way:

- I removed the parameters that define the position from the constructor as they just bloat the constructor and every `DisplayObject` defines setters for those anyway. If you insist on shoving all related values into one huge function call, I'd suggest creating a `static` method that returns the created object.
- That default value for color was rather odd. I changed it.
- the origin is in the center of each shape

Anyway, you use them **just like any `DisplayObject`**: create an instance and add it to a `DisplayObjectContainer`. That's the important point. They blend in with the api that's already in place. Your time line code could now look something like that:

```
import ezd.easydraw.EasyDraw;
stop();
var circle:Circle = new Circle(300, 0xff00);
circle.x = circle.y = 300;
addChild(circle);
```

Now if you want to add the circle to a container, a `Sprite` will do just fine:

```
import ezd.easydraw.EasyDraw;
stop();
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);

var circle:Circle = new Circle(300, 0xff00);
circle.x = circle.y = 300;
container.addChild(circle);
```